# How do I find Android SDK Manager path on Mac

Tags: android, macos, sdk

I have just downloaded Android studio on Mac, I only needed android sdk but could not find a link to download from and ended up downloading Android studio. How do I locate Android sdk path on Mac ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goto File --> Settings --> System Settings --> Android SDK

On top you can see the SDK location