# Deploying an Ionic 4 app in android complaints about Android SDK licenses not being accepted

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am trying to deploy a ionic app to android platform. While building I get the following error.

```
 BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error: /Users/sajimathew/personal/sajiideas/dosanddonts/frontend/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
     platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
```

I tried,

```
yes| ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
yes| ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update

yes| ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;28.0.3"
yes| ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-28"
```

none of these fixed the issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

first

[How do I find Android SDK Manager path on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996642/how-do-i-find-android-sdk-manager-path-on-mac)

Goto File --> Settings --> System Settings --> Android SDK

navigate to `sdk/tools/bin`

Run `sdkmanager`

```
./sdkmanager --licenses
```